# Can't stopPropagation when render subcomponents in componentDidMount()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here's my JS Bin Demo:

https://jsbin.com/baxipufozo/edit?html,js,output

I render `DragDropChild` in `DragDropParent componentDidMount`

but when I dragging child, the parent triggers `dragstart` too!

The same problem with `click` event

I tried `e.stopPropagation()` `e.nativeEvent.stopPropagation()` and `e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation()` but they all useless

So I can't stopPropagation when render subcomponents in componentDidMount(), but I *have to* render child in didMount.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can prevent the parent drag detection with a simple condition:

```
if(e.target.id === 'parent') {
      console.log('parent');
      e.dataTransfer.setData('Text','parent')
}
```

But why can't you render the child normally, inside its parent render method?